# Control post image size mobile

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Had to make some change to php file to get look and feel right on 3 column images for big screens. While looking perfect on large screens now on mobile phone devices is has blown the image up so big 70% is off the screen. I am trying to correct it for mobile devices by adding this to that same php file.

```
<?phpif(wp_is_mobile())the_post_thumbnail_url('271x337');?>
```

But it is giving me a Parse error, not sure where I have this wrong.

Comment: Separate your tag correctly `<?php if(wp_is_mobile()) the_post_thumbnail_url('271x337'); ?>`

Comment: yes, missed that. Got rid of Parse error but still did not fix my issue with reducing size of image on mobile phone display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. needed to add if(wp_is_mobile()) style="width: 300px;". So that when the image is being stacked on top of each other for smaller screen sizes I can control the image size for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if(wp_is_mobile()): the_post_thumbnail_url( array(50, 50) );  endif;?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.